# Использование Unreal Engine на Linux

Tags: linux, unreal-engine-4

Хочу перейти с Windows на Linux, но боюсь это делать так как мне нужен Unreal Engine. Из гугла я выяснил что есть официальная поддержка линукса, нужно просто клонировать репозиторий https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git и скомпилировать его, но этого репозитория не существует. Так вот есть ли способ юзать Unreal на линуксе? Есть ли у этого какие-то минусы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue4-on-github